# Count generated inputs integer values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have generated inputs like these:

```
<input type="text" id="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes_offer_price_0" name="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes[offer_price][0]" required="required" class="form-control offered-price">
<input type="text" id="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes_offer_price_1" name="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes[offer_price][1]" required="required" class="form-control offered-price">
```

These inputs can be more then two.

I need to count all prices in inputs, when user fill in and append on div element. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that should do what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/yvy986nc/

Snippet for JS.

```
  $('input.offered-price').keyup(function(){
      var val = 0;
      $('input.offered-price').each(function(){
         try{
              val += parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;    
          }catch(e){
              // just to catch parse int failures
          } 
      });
      $('#result').html(val);  
  });
```

Comment: Excellent! You have just saved me a lot of time! Thank you and best wishes! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can declare one hidden field with default value zero that increase when added control and decrease when removed control

Answer (score 1):

declare javascript variable to sum all input values when user fill them or leave them, look at the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/xb8gb8pm/2/

```
    var cart = {
    total: 0
};
$('.offered-price').blur(function () {
    cart.total = 0;
    $('.offered-price').each(function (i, idx) {
        price = $(idx).val().trim();
        cart.total += parseFloat(price !== '' ? price : 0);
    });
    $('.totalPrice').html('Total:'+cart.total);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing all Inputs**

If all your inputs will have the class "form-control offered-price" you can access them as an array of HTML elements like so `var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control.offered-price");`

**Appending HTML**

To append any HTML after an element, use `element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",yourHTML);` where `yourHTML` is a string containing valid HTML. You can also create an HTML element using `var myChildElement = document.createElement("div")` and then append that element to a parent element using `myParentElement.appendChild(myChildElement);`

**Summation of all input values**

One approach would be to attach an event listener to each input so that the div gets the recalculated sum every time an input changes, as in the code below.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control.offered-price");
inputs[inputs.length-1].insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div id='price_result'>");
(function(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i].addEventListener){
        arr[i].addEventListener("keyup",function(){
          document.getElementById("price_result").innerHTML = sumValues(arr);
        });
      }else{
        arr[i].attachEvent("onkeyup",function(){
          document.getElementById("price_result").innerHTML = sumValues(arr);
        });
      }
    }
})(inputs);
function sumValues(arr){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    sum += Number(arr[i].value,10);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes_offer_price_0" name="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes[offer_price][0]" required="required" class="form-control offered-price">
<input type="text" id="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes_offer_price_1" name="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes[offer_price][1]" required="required" class="form-control offered-price">
<input type="text" id="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes_offer_price_2" name="rfq_ironilbundle_quotes[offer_price][2]" required="required" class="form-control offered-price">
```